# Use variables in other function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function Main(BombPosTopr, BompPosLeftr){
if (CheckRight == false){
        //$("#Main").prepend('<div class="Effect" style="absolute; top:' + BombPosTopr + 'px; left: '+ BombPosLeftr +'px;"></div>');
        ArrayEffects.push(new EffectVoorBom(BombPosTopr,BombPosLeftr));
        BombPosLeftr += 30;
        }
        };

        this.explosionTime2 = setTimeout( function(){ 
        **self2.removeEffect();**
        }

}
function EffectBom(BombPosTopr, BompPosLeftr){
var self2 = this;
this.el = $('<div/>');
this.el.addClass('Effect');
this.el.css({position : 'absolute', top : BombPosTopr + 'px', left : BompPosLeftr+'px'});
$("#Main").prepend(this.el);


self2.removeEffect = function(){
**self2.el.remove();**
}
```

I have 2 functions and in my main I need to add Effects, so I put them in an array and use the object EffectBom.

Now the big problem is that I need to use self2.removeEffect() in my other function but it can't find it!

Thnx for reading - helping!

Comment: The nesting you have here is wrong.  You have one extra `}` in the middle and one missing `}` at the end.

Comment: Format your code properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the scope of the variable.  Add

```
var self2;
```

to the top of the file and change

```
var self2 = this;
```

to be

```
self2 = this;
```

Comment: While this would solve the problem, I cannot upvote an answer that suggests the use of global variables unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Do you propose an alternative given what has been presented by the asker?

Comment: The asker's code is incomplete and has some nesting problems, so at this point there is not enough information to determine a correct and optimal answer.

Comment: @Ding Agree with cdhowie that this is a simple minded answer and may cause more trouble than it's worth. A better answer would try to scope the variable a little better than a global